# How to send headers and query parameters in Angular10+

Tags: angular

It seems something like below could be done in Angular 2 or 3 but since RequestOptions can't be used in Angular 10+ not sure how to do this.

```
public getData(value: any): Observable<testData[]>{
        let queryParams = new HttpParams().append("test", value);
        let myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
        this.httpOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders, params: queryParams});
        return this.httpClient.get<testData[]>(this.url,this.httpOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `HttpHeaders` should solve the problem

```
import { HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

public getData(value: any): Observable<testData[]>{
    let queryParams = new HttpParams().set("test", value);
    let myHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
    myHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    this.httpOptions = { headers: myHeaders, params: queryParams};
    return this.httpClient.get<testData[]>(this.url,this.httpOptions);
}
```